# How can I get current logged user profile in django, into models?

Tags: django, django-models

How can I get current logged user profile in django, into models ?

I have this code:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = User.get_profile()
        self.empresa_id =   profile.idempresa
        self.empresa_id =  profile.id_comerx3c
        super(Cliente, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but doesn`t work..

Comment: You need an actual instance of the current user

Comment: You have to pass the User instance manually to your save function.

Comment: How can I do this? I`m newer in django...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a ModelForm, you have three choices:

1. Set the profile when you instantiate the form
2. Create the object instance in a view, but not commit it, then set the profile property and
   commit the save
3. Pass the profile to the save method, and set the property before
   calling super

If you're just dealing with a Model, you have two choices:

1. Pass the profile in when you instantiate the object
2. Set the profile on an instance of your object before you call save

Comment: I`m using this: 'def editaCliente(request, pessoa_id=None):
    if pessoa_id:
        cliente = Cliente.objects.get(id=pessoa_id)
    else:
        cliente = None

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formPessoa = ClienteForm(request.POST, instance=cliente)
        if formPessoa.is_valid():
            cliente = formPessoa.save()

            if cliente:
                return HttpResponse('Cliente salvo com sucesso!')
    else:
        formPessoa = ClienteForm(instance=cliente)

    return render_to_response('cliente_novo.html',locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request),
    )'

Comment: I get the answer...

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formPessoa = ClienteForm(request.POST, instance=cliente)
        if formPessoa.is_valid():
            profile = request.user.get_profile()
            cliente = formPessoa.save(commit=False)
            cliente.empresa_id = profile.idempresa 
            cliente.idrepresentante = profile.id_comerx3c
            cliente = formPessoa.save()

            if cliente:
                return HttpResponse('Cliente salvo com sucesso!')
    else:
        formPessoa = ClienteForm(instance=cliente)

Thanks for all..